# Make the TOC page number bold for `\frontmatter` that using 'section' style without bold the other sections page number in `\mainmatter`

Tags: formatting, tocloft

I hope that you are doing well. I want to ask, how can I bold the page number for the `\frontmatter` in the TOC while using the 'section' style i.e `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TEXT}`? The reason I used the 'section' style is that I want the spacing to be as in the 'section' style. I have tried to change the font style as `\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{bfseries}`, but it will change the page number (in TOC) for the other sections in the `\mainmatter` as well, which I don't want that from happening and if I used `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TEXT}`, it does bold the page number, however, I cannot control the spacing. I want the spacing for the front matter to be as in the following figure but the page number to be bold.

[image]

I really hope that there is someone who can help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the formatting options/changes to the ToC at the correct locations within your document. So, just after `\frontmatter`, add

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}}
```

and just after `\mainmatter`, add

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries}}

\sloppy
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]
\begin{table}\caption{First table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{First figure}\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]
\begin{table}\caption{Second table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]
\begin{table}\caption{Third table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{Third figure}\end{figure}

\chapter{Final chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]
\begin{table}\caption{Final table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}\caption{Final figure}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For this to work if you're using [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir), you'll need to change `cftsectionpagefont`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It does work properly and the results are like what I want.